# Add a scale bar to a map

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

Is it possible to add a scale bar to a map?

I was hoping for something 'built in' like:

```
map.addControl(new mapboxgl.Scale({position: 'bottom-right'}));
```

Seems it was possible via a leaflet control in the classic js

```
L.control.scale().addTo(map);
```

Comment: Latest version looks like:
`map.addControl(new mapboxgl.ScaleControl({maxWidth:100}));`

Comment: The answer is correct but it is weird not to have a `position` property to change the position of the scale. It is located bottom-left custom , but I need it to have bottom-right so I had to change the css properties.

Answer (score 14):

`map.addControl(new mapboxgl.ScaleControl({position: 'bottom-right'}));`

The documentation can be found [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/markers/#scalecontrol)

- disclaimer - I work at Mapbox

Comment: Absolutely awesome :-)

Comment: @mollymerp I want to have a scale when I design a style. Is there anything like a "Scale Layer" ?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: mapboxgl.Scale is not a constructor

Comment: It seems now to be mapboxgl.ScaleControl (previously mapboxgl.Scale).

Comment: `{position: 'bottom-right'}` does not work for me, but I'm happy with the default left bottom position 

Comment: To get the scale to the bottom right, I first defined the scale using 'const scale = new mapboxgl.ScaleControl({maxWidth: 80, unit: 'metric'})' then added it to map like so: 'map.addControl(scale, 'bottom-right')'